Does the Sum of Weighted Inverse Roots of Cumulative Samples Scale with Total Samples?
I have a sampling process defined over a sample space $\{1,2,\dots, M\}$, and $M$ is the number of items.
The sampling is done in $B$ batches, and each batch is repeated $\ell_i$ times. In each repeat, we can sample $c$ items, and we can sample the same item multiple times using any sampling rules.
Let $n_i(j)$ denote the number of times the $j$-th item is sampled in $i$-th batch, and $N_i(j):=\sum_{t=1}^{i-1} n_{t}(j)$ denotes the cumulative number of times the $j$-th item has been sampled up to $i$-th batch and excluding the $i$-th batch.
The constrains are $\forall i,j, N_i(j)\geq 0, N_i(j)\geq N_{i-1}(j)$, and for all batch $b:1\leq b\leq B$, the total sample times is denoted as $K_b := \sum_{i=1}^{b} \sum_{j=1}^M n_i(j)= \sum_{i=1}^b c\cdot\ell_i$.
The question is whether
$\sum_{i=1}^B\ell_i \cdot(\sum_{j=1}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{\max\{1,N_{i}(j)\}}}) \leq O(\sqrt{K_B})?$
We are particularly interested in two scenarios:

fixed batch length, $\ell_1 = \dots = \ell_B = \frac{K_B}{cB}$;
Exponentially increasing batch lengths: $\ell_i = 2^i$.

I would appreciate any insight or proof on whether the inequality holds in these cases and why.
